# What is the best way to log and accumulate exceptions from different servers?

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api, logging, nlog

Currently, we have a few instances of WebApi applications on different physical servers. Sometimes, some exceptions happen and reduce the quality of service. As the exceptions log on servers themselves, and we need to check them individually, it will take a while to be aware of the problem.

For collecting all exceptions, I considered Exception Filters, but we have some try/catch without rethrowing exceptions, so we lose some exception.
I also considered FirstChanceException Event, to log all exceptions at the first chance.
For accumulating exceptions in one place, I considered Nlog, and use a shared folder.
Are they good approaches? Is there a better approach or an open-source library for these?

I would like to accumulate all exceptions (whatever they handled or not) from all servers to a single place to check and process quickly.

Comment: This is too broad - almost as broad as designing a database, a farm or an application. *It depends* on a *lot* of things - the actual business requirements, the environment, whether you want it for operations, administration or developer debugging (different scenarios with very different latency, detail requirements). If a site is down you want to notify the operators as fast as possible. *None* of those concerns is addressed by a local logging library - by definition, they only log locally.

Comment: You can use eg Application Insights to get both monitoring and detailed diagnostics, even in the free tier. Or you could take advantage of Windows Event log's push subscritptions to quickly log local events (far faster than any logging library) and have them propagate to a central server. Or you can use a library like [Logary](https://github.com/logary/logary) that collects both logs and metrics and can push them to a time-series database like Influx or a [distributed tracing system like Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/)

Comment: In fact, it would be a good idea to check Logary and Azure AppInsights even if you don't use them in the end. They demonstrate the issues involved, the difference between metrics, operational messages and detailed logs. The cloud-based services like Azure AppInsights, Google Stackdriver or CloudWatch allow you to quickly get started with metrics and logs analysis

Comment: Is the problem here that one issue will result in multiple error logs?

Comment: No, the problem is that we find the error log too late when the QoS has declined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos), I've finally come up with this solution.

I took advantage of [AppDomain.FirstChanceException Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception?view=netframework-4.8) to find all exceptions in my app.

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += FirstChanceHandler;
}

static void FirstChanceHandler(object source, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Then send them to [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com), which is an open-source time-series database.

```
var payload = new LineProtocolPayload();
const string measurement = "logs";
var memoryLoad = new LineProtocolPoint(measurement,
     new Dictionary<string, object>
     {
         {"message", e.Exception?.Message,},
     },
     new Dictionary<string, string>
     {
         {"host", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME")},
         {"app", "{my app name}"},
     },
     DateTime.UtcNow);
payload.Add(memoryLoad);       
var influxResult = Client.WriteAsync(payload, ct).Result;
```

And finally, I showed the result in [Grafana](https://grafana.com), and this is the final result.

[image]